# Is there a way to make SegmentedControl clickable again once selected - iOS

Tags: ios, uisegmentedcontrol, uiactionsheet

Here I am implementing the SegmentedControl in iOS7. One of the segment will pops up the UIActionSheet. My design is that once one of the button of the actionsheet is selected, then the actionsheet will dismissed itself, and that segment in the segmented control is determined as selected. The issue is when I want bring up the action sheet again from the same selected segment in the segmented control. Here, for now, I need to select the different segment of the segmented control bar to unactivated the segment that is bound with the actionsheet and then later touch the segment again to show the action sheet.

Should there be a way to inactivate the segment?

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever tried to set state of `UISegmentedControl` to momentary?

You can do this in interface builder or in code like `[self.mySegmentedControl setMomentary:YES];`.

Comment: Thanks, this works, but I also want to keep the previously selected segment to be highlighted as well. Using momentary made the selected segment flashing instead of highlighted.